# window.open() adds exrtra forward slash ("/") before the query parameters start

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, angular

I am trying to redirect user to a webpage using the following code:

```
let url="http://www.someUrl.com";
let queryParams="?abcd=pqr"; // query parameters
url=url+queryParams;

window.open(url,"_blank");
```

When I see the link in the browser it shows as: **http://www.someUrl.com/?abcd=pqr**

You can see that it adds an extra **"/"** 
Please help me remove that extra **"/"**

Comment: That's how browser interpret the url. `http://` is the scheme, `www.someUrl.com` is the domain, `/` is the path, `?abcd=pqr` is the query string. Even when you type [https://www.google.com?a=1](https://www.google.com?a=1) in the browser you will get `https://www.google.com/?a=1` instead.

Comment: Thank you I was also thinking the same, just needed a second opinion on it. Thanks.